# Mapping json to C# object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, deserialization

I have a json file that get's generated like this

```
[
    {
        "test1": "Pirates", 
        "test2": "Hello World"
    },
    {
        "test1": "Pirates", 
        "test2": "Hello World"
    }
]
```

From one of the questions I came across, I used this link [Json 2 Cshartp Object](http://json2csharp.com/) and see the class that should be made.  However... It's supposed to be an array I think, but it has no name?  So I tried making the object like so

```
public class pirateships
{
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then call `DeserializeObject<T>()` using

```
pirateships coords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pirateships>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

But it's still saying it can't deserialize correctly.  I tried making it an array of pirateships but still failed.  Thanks very much in advance for the assistance guys.

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: The class should probably be named `PirateShip`, in order to follow conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You JSON string is an array of `pirateships`, so you have to deserialize it as `pirateships[]`:

```
pirateships[] coords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pirateships[]>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Note that you could do different types, e.g. I'd suggest `IList<pirateships>` (Json.NET will choose some appropriate concrete type).

Comment: Aha!  I should have realized this.  That was exactly it!  Thank you both very much!